# Задержка при работе Yolo на прямой трансляции

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

Написал скрипт на Python - обнаружение предмета на прямой трансляции и подачи сигнала в чат-бот телеграмма. Все работает, но использует всю оперативную память из за этого работоспособность скрипта желает лучшего. Оперативной памяти 30 гигов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать или исправить скрипт, чтобы работал хорошо. код прилагаю:

```
import cv2
import queue
import time
import threading
from ultralytics import YOLO
import telebot
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '...'
CHAT_ID = '...'
q = queue.Queue()
model = YOLO(r'best.pt')
telegram_bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
timestamps_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Квадрат', 'Время'])
notification_sent = {'квадрат 1': False, 'квадрат 2': False}  # Flag to track if notification has been sent for each square

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp:...')
def record_timestamp(region):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    timestamps_df.loc[len(timestamps_df)] = [region, current_time]
    timestamps_df.to_excel('Скрепер.xlsx', index=False)
def send_telegram_message(message):
    telegram_bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)
def Receive():
    print("start Receive")
    global cap
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    q.put(frame)
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        q.put(frame)
def Display():
    print("Start Displaying")
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            frame = q.get()
            results = model.track(frame, persist=True)
            annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
            cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (100, 900), (600, 700), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (1250, 710), (1800, 900), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            
            for result in results[0].boxes.xyxy:
                center_x = int((result[0] + result[2]) / 2)
                center_y = int((result[1] + result[3]) / 2)
                if 100 < center_x < 600 and 700 < center_y < 900 and not notification_sent['квадрат 1']:
                    send_telegram_message("Объект обнаружен в 1 квадрате!")
                    record_timestamp('квадрат 1')
                    notification_sent['квадрат 1'] = True
                if 1250 < center_x < 1800 and 710 < center_y < 900 and not notification_sent['квадрат 2']:
                    send_telegram_message("Объект обнаружен во 2 квадрате!")
                    record_timestamp('квадрат 2')
                    notification_sent['квадрат 2'] = True
            cv2.imshow("YOLOv8 Tracking", annotated_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=Receive)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=Display)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: попробуй сделать чтобы чек происходил раз в +-секунду, а не каждый кадр

Comment: и так же убедись, что while выполняется не быстрее, чем частота захвата кадров (смысла нет дважды проверять один и тот же кадр)

Answer (score 0):

я решил проблему при помощи такого кода:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO(r'best.pt')
results = model.track(source='rtsp:...', show=True)
video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(results)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_cap.read()
    model.cpu()

    if not ret:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

video_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

но теперь я не могу отобразить фигуры на экране этим кодом:
annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (100, 900), (600, 700), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (1250, 710), (1800, 900), (0, 0, 255), 2)

кто нибудь знает, как это исправить?

Answer (score -4):

Освобождение ресурсов: Убедитесь, что все ресурсы, такие как объекты cv2.VideoCapture, правильно освобождаются после их использования. Вы можете добавить cap.release() и cv2.destroyAllWindows() в блок finally для гарантированного освобождения ресурсов даже в случае ошибок.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        p1 = threading.Thread(target=Receive)
        p2 = threading.Thread(target=Display)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
    finally:
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Уменьшение частоты кадров: Если ваша программа обрабатывает кадры слишком быстро, попробуйте уменьшить частоту обработки кадров. Вы можете добавить паузу между итерациями обработки кадров с использованием time.sleep().

```
while True:
    if not q.empty():
        frame = q.get()
        # ... остальной код ...
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Добавьте паузу, чтобы уменьшить частоту обработки кадров
```

Использование меньших изображений: Если возможно, уменьшите размер входных изображений перед передачей их в модель YOLO. Это уменьшит потребление памяти.

```
while True:
    if not q.empty():
        frame = q.get()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (new_width, new_height))  # Уменьшите размер изображения
        results = model.track(frame, persist=True)
        # ... остальной код ...
```

Обработка ошибок и исключений: Убедитесь, что ваш код обрабатывает ошибки и исключения правильно, чтобы избежать утечек ресурсов или непредвиденных проблем.
Мониторинг использования памяти: Используйте инструменты мониторинга использования памяти, такие как psutil, чтобы отслеживать, какие части вашей программы потребляют больше всего памяти.
Поиск утечек памяти: Проведите анализ вашего кода на предмет утечек памяти, убедившись, что все ресурсы правильно освобождаются после использования.
Оптимизация модели: В зависимости от модели YOLO и конфигурации, которую вы используете, может потребоваться настроить параметры модели для оптимизации памяти и производительности.
Применение этих изменений должно помочь уменьшить использование оперативной памяти и улучшить работоспособность вашего скрипта. Однако следует помнить, что использование библиотеки YOLO может быть ресурсоемким процессом, и настройка оптимальных параметров может потребовать некоторых исследований и экспериментов.